# Alternative to nested Directory.GetParent() to browse through folders in Project?

Tags: c#, path

I currently have a project with a few folders in its structure. I am working on the `PlayerDataHandler` class and I need to access an XML file located in `/Assets/Data`.

[image: Folder Hierarchy]

For now, the only way I found to get my stream from `/Source/Meta/PlayerInformation.cs` to `/Assets/Data` was writing the following lines of code:

```
 string xpathXmlPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
 xpathXmlPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(xpathXmlPath).FullName).FullName).FullName + @"\Assets\Data\XPathElements.xml";
```

I am sure there is a cleaner way of achieving this. Any suggestions?

Ps. I have also tried the following, results in the same path (`\Overwatcher\OverwatcherWpf\OverwatcherWpf\bin\Debug\`):

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```